# Create new rows in dataframe with values from a list/dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using several data frames that I will combine integer values to deduce a final score. Sort of like a 'final grade' calculation, say with perhaps a 'Test' weigh and a 'HW' weigh, to give a picture.

Anyway, I would like to use a list of index values, and iterate through each of the data frames to see if they existed in each. If the data frame doesn't have an 'entry' for an index, or character, in this dataframe, I would like to add a row for the character in the dataframe, then assign a constant value to each month entry. The dataframes that I am looking in have months by column and rows by characters.

***I have thought about using either a list or a dictionary. Here is the list that I want to use, just to show you each of the characters:***

```
my_list = 
['Sonic','Knuckles','Shadow','Tails','Amy']
```

***Here's an example of one of the dataframes that I would like to add it to.***

```
penalties_df = 
                       Jan 18  Feb 18  Mar 18  Apr 18
Character                                     
Sonic                  1.0     2.0     3.0    1.0
Knuckles               2.0     2.0     2.0    2.0
Amy                    1.0     2.0     1.0    1.0
```

I haven't received anything from `Shadow` and `Tails` which is why they don't have a row.

```
Shadow                 xxx     xxx     xxx    xxx
Tails                  xxx     xxx     xxx    xxx
```

***My desired output:***

```
penalties_df = 
                           Jan 18  Feb 18  Mar 18  Apr 18
    Character                                     
    Sonic                  1.0     2.0     3.0    1.0
    Knuckles               2.0     2.0     2.0    2.0
    Shadow                 0.0     0.0     0.0    0.0
    Tails                  0.0     0.0     0.0    0.0
    Amy                    1.0     2.0     1.0    1.0
```

The '`xxx`'s are just placeholders to indicate where I haven't received any data from that character (`Shadow` and `Tails`). I run my code periodically, and for times that I run my code up until I receive data for a character, I would like to create a row and assign a value of 0, by checking if the character exists in the dataframe.

I have considered `.append()`, but I do not have an existing data frame to append to `penalties_df`. I only want to create new rows.

Could I create a dictionary to access for this scenario? I would think my dictionary would be something like this, however, it would be redundant to have a bunch of repeating 0's typed in (I only have a piece of what I would use here to keep my question short):

```
penalties_none = {
        "Sonic" : 0,
        "Knuckles" : 0,
        "Shadow" : 0,
        "Tails" : 0,
        "Amy" : 0,
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the differences in names between `df.index` and `my_list`. Then you need to make a df with these differences and append to your main df.

```
df.append(pd.DataFrame(index=list(set(my_list) - set(df.index)))).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
res = df.append(pd.DataFrame(index=list(set(my_list) - set(df.index)))).fillna(0)
res.index.name='Character'
```

Output:

```
             Apr_18  Feb_18  Jan_18  Mar_18
Character                                
Sonic         1.0     2.0     1.0     3.0
Knuckles      2.0     2.0     2.0     2.0
Amy           1.0     2.0     1.0     1.0
Tails         0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
Shadow        0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) function:

```
my_list = ['Sonic','Knuckles','Shadow','Tails','Amy']

penalties_df = penalties_df.reindex(mylist, fill_value = 0)
```